# Gstreamer - losing "last" buffer

Tags: gstreamer

I'm using gstreamer with souphttp, demux and appsink. The appsink is attached to demux dynamically on new pad request. The hlsdemux, i use, seems to be dropping "last" buffer as I miss about 0.5 seconds of packets.

I retrieve packets based on "new_sample" signal.

Any known issue with respect to demuxers-->appsink with dynamic pad? Should I have to do anything specific after EOS received, or new pad added?